# Display-buffer-at-bottom to popup a message

Tags: elisp

I wrote such a function to pop-up a buffer at bottom

```
(defun popup-new-message (msg)
  (interactive
   (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "pop-message")))
     (with-current-buffer buffer
       (insert msg))
     (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-at-bottom . nil)))
   ))
(popup-new-message "It's time to have a rest.")
```

When run it, nothing happened.

What's the problem?

I checked that functions of `generate-new-buffer` and `display-message` working

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
(let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "pop-message")))
  (print buffer))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: #<buffer pop-message<2>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your (interactive S-EXP is not closed correctly.